# How can I diagnose and fix my absurdly long Meteor build times?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm

I have a small to medium sized web app using meteor 1.5, react, and redux. For a long time I've been experiencing horrendous start-up times of around 3-4 minutes. My app uses npm packages, meteor packages, and local meteor packages. I was able to remove a bunch of un-needed local packages and I got the build time down to around 2+ minutes, but that didn't last and now it's up to literally 20 minutes.

I've tried using the meteor profiler many times, and while the times it reports are still themselves unacceptable, they're a lot shorter than the actual load time. The bulk of the wait comes between the completion of the 'prepareProjectForBuild' step, and the start of the 'Build App' step, where the profiler outputs nothing. When the 'Build App' step completes it claims to have taken around 200 seconds. Still a lousy build time IMO, but I'd kill for it at this point.

Comment: [Don't push any more updates to your app: No more build time issues.](https://i.imgur.com/WcgkdYX.jpg)

Comment: Switch to another framework. Long build time is not going to go away

Comment: I know Meteor isn't the ideal choice but I'm kind of stuck with it for now. A 20 minute build time is obviously something pathological.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar sized project and have squeezed build times down to around 1min. I can only tell you from my experiecne what I did to reduce my build times:

**A - Code considerations**

**1. Move as much as possible 'manual' code into factory methods**

This means, that similar creational code that repeats a lot, can be easily reduced to a few creational factory functions. This also improves test coverage.

Where:

- espcially creations of collections. The most collections differ only
  in their schema and some special cases of pubs/methods. A lot of code
  is duplicate.
- schema
- common publications (e.g. only title and id, which occurs often)
- methods that follow a certain 'standard' pattern
- any recurring pattern of objects created at runtime

**2. Don't mess around with thousands of circular imports**

It does not crash your app. But keeping a clear and encapsulated structure may reduce lookup time on imports. Makes also your code easier to maintain.

**3. Move asset files out of your project**

I know that is a hard one, especially when structures have tighten over time. But when I had to move all my asset files away to a cdn and only reference the paths it gave a good boost to my build time.

**4. Npm dependencies in packages**

Instead of hard-wiring npm deps in your packages (or the ones where you are in control), you may use

```
tmeasday:check-npm-versions
```

to soft reference them, so that your meteor app is responsible to manage them, reducing npm's urge to dedupe packages.

**5. Move to npm where possible**

The time will come, where meteor shifts to npm anyway. So make your packages npm packages where possible now and safe the build time later.

edit:
..................................................

**6. Draw services out of your app into standalone services**

When you have services, that serve only one function, move them out of your app. That may apply for:

- notifcation services
- engines (workflows, process-eninges)
- logging / tracking
- simple transactions
- admin panel (usually anyway just manipulating collections)
- other parts of the app, that serve only administrative purposes

..................................................

**B - Other Considerations**

**1. Do not develop meteor on Windows (unless you need to)**

This advice is a little bit flawed, because I can't tell you why, but I perceived on several machines (my own, vm, colleagues, workplace) a **way** slower update,build and package build process than on linux or mac. Compiling native code like bcrypt is here slow as hell. Maybe someone has an insight on that?

**2. SSD makes everything faster**

Common sense already.

**Note:** I can't tell how good the boost is by a particular one of these described methods. I just tried all of these over time and got a good build over time.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Unfortunately for me it must have been some issue with meteor. I removed all my meteor files and started a new project and now everything works beautifully